# Google checkout integration with magento

Tags: magento, google-checkout, magento-1.7

I'm trying to add Google Checkout to my magento 1.7.0.0 shop.  I've traced the issue and it seems to fail during posting to google's server because when I try to read the response it's false.

The error I get is: **Google Checkout: Invalid response from Google Checkout server**

I'm using magento 1.7, google sandbox with sandbox credentials, verified bank account, unchecked digitally signed carts, but am using a self-signed certificate on my development machine, and API version 2.2.

The issue is happening in app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/Model/Api/Xml/Abstract.php on lines 174, 175

```
$http = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
$http->write('POST', $url, '1.1', $headers, $xml);
$response = $http->read();
```

Comment: Tried turning SSL off on frontend and still have the same issue. Deleted cache/session for good measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with it being a local environment.  The issue was either with Google not being able to communicate or with my tld ending in .dev.  Possibly Google rejected the request for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Not a `PHP` dev ~

Is this a *sandbox* `server to server` (Shopping Cart) POST? Check:

- that you are using *[sandbox credentials](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API#https_auth_scheme)* in your headers;
- that you are posting to a *[sandbox url](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API#urls_for_posting)* for the xml you are sending

Note - unchecking "digital cart" only means your account will *also* accept HTML API cart POSTs, but it doesn't mean you can send XML without a digital signature *if doing direct FORM post to Google* - re: in XML API, you [have 2 options to send `XML` data](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API#create_checkout_cart):

1. Direct `HTML FORM` POST to Google (must include signature), or;
2. Server to Server POST to Google (must use Basic Auth credentials)

You can also check your *sandbox Integration Console* for detailed error messages:

`Tools -> Integration Console`

Hth...

Comment: I'm doing a server to server post.  I'm using sandbox credentials and posting to the sandbox url.

Will it matter if my ssl certificate is self signed?

Comment: @Nate - In *sandbox*, SSL isn't needed....anything in your `Integration Console`? If there's nothing in the IG, from personal experience its almost always an issue of using Production Merchant ID/Key in sandbox (they're **not** interchangeable). What url are you `POST`ing to (and what xml are you posting)?

Comment: There's nothing in my integration console, but I'm definitely using the right credentials. I have this error 'You must use HTTP Basic Authentication for API calls (username=Seller ID, password=Merchant Key)' form the 23, but I've tried to check out since then.

Comment: @Nate `You must use HTTP Basic Authentication for API calls` is likely the issue. As above, your HTTP request headers must include Basic Authentication credentials (*sandbox* mid/key in your case) - [as described here](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API#https_auth_scheme) (same as above).

Comment: Yep, this is how it's being sent: $http->write('POST', $url, '1.1', $headers, $xml);